# Implement a condition into a array

Tags: python, arrays, conditional-statements

I'm trying to implement another condition into my program but can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
print ("Welcome to the winning card program.")
year_one=[]
year_one.append(eval(input("Enter the salary individual 1 got in year 1:  ")))
year_one.append(eval(input("Enter the salary individual 2 got in year 1:  ")))
 if year_one[0]==year_one[1]:
   print("Error. The amount are the same, please reenter information.")
year_two=[]
year_two.append(eval(input("Enter the salary individual 1 got in year 2:  ")))
year_two.append(eval(input("Enter the salary individual 2 got in year 2:  ")))
 if year_two[0]==year_two[1]:
   print("Error. The amount are the same, please reenter information.")
year_three=[]
year_three.append(eval(input("Enter the salary individual 1 got in year 3:  ")))
year_three.append(eval(input("Enter the salary individual 2 got in year 3:  ")))
  if year_three[0]==year_three[1]:
   print("Error. The amount are the same, please reenter information.")
year_four=[]
year_four.append(eval(input("Enter the salary individual 1 got in year 4:  ")))
year_four.append(eval(input("Enter the salary individual 2 got in year 4:  ")))
 if year_four[0]==year_four[1]:
  print("Error. The amount are the same, please reenter information.")
year_five=[]
year_five.append(eval(input("Enter the salary individual 1 got in year 4:  ")))
year_five.append(eval(input("Enter the salary individual 2 got in year 4:  ")))
 if year_five[0]==year_five[1]:
  print("Error. The amount are the same, please reenter information.")
individual1_total=year_one[0]+year_two[0]+year_three[0]+year_four[0]+year_five[0]
individual2_total=year_one[1]+year_two[1]+year_three[1]+year_four[1]+year_five[1]
 if (individual1_total>individual2_total):
  print("Individual one has the highest salary.")
 elif (individual2_total>individual1_total):
  print("Individual two has the highest salary.")
```

If the salary for the two individuals for a particular year is exactly the same, you should print an error and make the user enter both the salaries again for that year. (The condition is the salaries should not be the exact same).

I look forward to everyone's feedback.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: HI new contributor, we are on it.

Comment: You should look into for loops.  Your code has way too many repetitions and you are not leveraging the benefits of storing your data in lists.  More reading on lists and indexing is what you need at this point.

Comment: @surge10 Thank you!

Comment: @AlainT. I'll look more into it. I definitely need to work on tightening the code. Thanks for input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so building on surge10 here is a more complete replacement of your code. I broke all the pieces down into functions, and made a dictionary as my in in-memory database.

```
total_years = 5
years = {}

def dict_key(year, userId):
    return '{}:{}'.format(year, userId)

def get_user_data(year, userId):
    key = dict_key(year, userId)
    years[key] = float(input("Enter the salary individual {} got in year {}:".format(userId, year)))

def get_year_salaray(year, userId):
    key = dict_key(year, userId)
    return years[key]

def any_salaries_match(year, userIds):
    for userLeft in userIds:
        salary_left = get_year_salaray(year, userLeft)
        for userRight in userIds:
            if userLeft != userRight:
                salary_right = get_year_salaray(year, userRight)
                if salary_left == salary_right:
                    return True

def get_user_totals(userId):
    total = 0
    for key, value in years.items():
        if ':{}'.format(userId) in key:
            total += value
    return total

for x in range(total_years):
    year = x + 1
    data_invalid = True
    while data_invalid:
        userOne = 1
        userTwo = 2
        get_user_data(year, userOne)
        get_user_data(year, userTwo)

        if any_salaries_match(year, [userOne, userTwo]):
            print("Error. The amount are the same, please reenter information.")
        else:
            data_invalid = False

userOneTotal = get_user_totals(1)
userTwoTotal = get_user_totals(2)

if (userOneTotal>userTwoTotal):
  print("Individual one has the highest salary.")
elif (userTwoTotal>userOneTotal):
  print("Individual two has the highest salary.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the functions break down. It definitely helps me understand the importance on simplifying and building a dictionary. Awesome stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Since we were checking for five different years I used a loop for those five years
Later we can get it back into individual years.

```
print ("Welcome to the winning card program.")
years=[]

for x in range(5):

    # range starts at zero so add one all the time
    # to start it at one
    y = str(x + 1)

    errors = True
    while errors:

        salary_one = input("Enter the salary individual 1 got in year " + y + ":  ")
        salary_two = input("Enter the salary individual 2 got in year " + y + ":  ")

        if salary_one == salary_two:
            print("Error. The amount are the same, please reenter information.")
            errors = True
        else:
            years.append([salary_one, salary_two])
            errors = False

year_one = years[0]
year_two = years[1]

...
print(year_one)
print(year_two)
...
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. Thanks for insight! I'm definitely going to reevaluate my code.